# Nested for loop is incorrect for the second number

Tags: python, for-loop

I am testing a simple nested for loop that combines year and month

```
year_time = range(2014, 2016)
month_time = [
    '0101', '0201', '0301', '0401',
    '0501', '0601', '0701', '0801',
    '0901', '1001', '1101', '1201'
]
for year_time in year_time:
    for month_time in month_time:
        print (str(year_time) + month_time)
```

The ideal output is `20140101, 20140201 ... 20151101, 20151201`. However, the actual output is `20140101, 20140201 ... 20151`.

Where do I get wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for-loop variable (`month_time`) is shadowing the list after first iteration of outer loop (after year is changed), so the second iteration of inner loop iterates over string `'1201'`.
What you need is to change names:

```py
years = range(2014, 2016)
months = ['0101', '0201', '0301', '0401', '0501', '0601', '0701', '0801', '0901', '1001', '1101', '1201']
for year in years:
    for month in months:
        print("".join([str(year), month]))
```

(I also replaced concatenation with a `.join`, that's a more pythonic way to join strings, especially if you have more than two of them)

Answer (score 0):

That worked for me, you should try to use 'step', like **range(1,10,2)**
or ,instead, multiple range()...

```
year_time = range(2014,2016)
year_time_2 = range(2015,2017)

month_time = ['0101', '0201', '0301', '0401', '0501', '0601', '0701', '0801', '0901', '1001', 
              '1101', '1201']

# Range for 2014
for x in year_time:
        for month in month_time:
            print(str(x) + month)
            
# Range for 2015-2016
for n in year_time_2:
    for month in month_time:
        print(str(n) + month)
```

Comment: This doesn't explain what the problem was.

Comment: Because there wasn't an error, just add a new range and that's done ! :)

Comment: No, there was no error, but there was unexpected behaviour which was caused by a very specific mistake in the code.